# Is it possible to loop on composite action `uses` in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

Below is my workflow that calls composite workflow thrice by passing different `action` arguments:

```
---

name: poc - AD 

on:

  workflow_dispatch
    
jobs:

  TEMPORARY_DB:      

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:   

      - name: Composite Dropping and Restore POC.
        id: dropdb
        uses: mybank/DevOps/mongodocker@tmp
        with:
          action: 'drop'


      - name: Composite Dropping and Restore POC.
        id: restoredb
        uses: mybank/DevOps/mongodocker@tmp
        with:
          action: 'restore'


      - name: Composite Dropping and Restore POC.
        id: createdb
        uses: mybank/DevOps/mongodocker@tmp
        with:
          action: 'create'
```

Is it possible to have a single step and loop it thrice by passing  `drop`, `restore` and `create`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no loop as such, but you could have a [matrix](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs):

> A matrix strategy lets you use variables in a single job definition to automatically create multiple job runs that are based on the combinations of the variables.

In your case, that would be something like:

```yaml
jobs:
  TEMPORARY_DB:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 1  # assuming they should run in series
      matrix:
        action: ['drop', 'restore', 'create']
    steps:   
      - name: Composite Dropping and Restore POC.
        uses: mybank/DevOps/mongodocker@tmp
        with:
          action: ${{ matrix.action }}
```

Comment: is is possible to have strategy only for this step `- name: Composite` and not other subsequent steps under job `TEMPORARY_DB`

Comment: No, as you can see from the linked documentation the strategy applies to the _job_, not a step. But you can have as many jobs as you like within a workflow, so if there are more steps to run just define another job with `needs: TEMPORARY_DB`.

Comment: Thanks @jonrshape i had a slightly tweaked query around this posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76814996/how-to-write-github-action-strategy-matrix-having-different-variables-in-each-ru